# ¿Cómo subir imagenes al servidor con Selenium en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagen, servidor, selenium

Estoy usando Selenium y Python, y me he encontrado con este problema. Tengo que subir una imagen al servidor y no veo la forma.

El código HTML es este.

```
<a id="file_upload" href="javascript:;">Añadir imágenes</a>
```

Cuando se hace click en este link se abre la típica ventana del sistema para seleccionar archivos.

Por el momento lo único que he logrado hacer es localizar el elemento y hacer click en él.

```
 img_upload = driver.find_element_by_id("file_upload")
 img_upload .click()
```

Tabién he probado así pero no pasa nada

```
img_upload = driver.find_element_by_id("file_upload")
img_upload.send_keys(img_path)
```

¿Alguna ídea de como poder subir la imagen?

---

Bueno, ya sé que lo ésto es una locura porque está codificado... pero es el fragmento de código de JavaScript que controla lo de subir el archivo... Lo pongo por si sirviera de algo.

```
function s() {
    var e, s;
    i.extend(this, {
        init: function(u) {
            var c, l, d, m, h, f, p = this,
                g = p.getRuntime();

            e = u, d = o.extList2mimes(e.accept, g.can("filter_by_extension")),
                l = g.getShimContainer(),

                l.innerHTML = '<input id="' + g.uid + '" type="file" style="font-size:999px;
            opacity: 0;
            "'+(e.multiple&&g.can("
            select_multiple ")?"
            multiple ":"
            ")+               
            (e.directory && g.can("select_folder") ?
                "webkitdirectory directory" : "") +
            (d ? ' accept="' + d.join(",") + '"' : "") + " />",
            c = n.get(g.uid), i.extend(c.style,

                    {
                        position: "absolute",
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0,
                        width: "100%",
                        height: "100%"
                    }), m = n.get(e.browse_button), s = n.getStyle(m, "z-index") || "auto", g.can("summon_file_dialog") && ("static" === n.getStyle(m, "position") &&

                    (m.style.position = "relative"), r.addEvent(m, "click", function(e) {
                        var t = n.get(g.uid);
                        t && !t.disabled &&

                            t.click(), e.preventDefault()
                    }, p.uid), p.bind("Refresh", function() {
                        h = parseInt(s, 10) || 1, n.get(e.browse_button).style.zIndex = h, this.getRuntime().getShimContainer().style.zIndex = h - 1
                    })), f = g.can("summon_file_dialog") ? m : l, r.addEvent(f, "mouseover", function()

                    {
                        p.trigger("mouseenter")
                    }, p.uid), r.addEvent(f, "mouseout", function()

                    {
                        p.trigger("mouseleave")
                    }, p.uid), r.addEvent(f, "mousedown", function()

                    {
                        p.trigger("mousedown")
                    }, p.uid), r.addEvent(n.get(e.container), "mouseup", function() {
                    p.trigger("mouseup")
                }, p.uid),

                (g.can("summon_file_dialog") ? c : m).setAttribute("tabindex", -1), c.onchange = function x() {
                    if (p.files = [], i.each(this.files, function(i) {
                            var n = "";
                            return e.directory && "." == i.name ? !0 : (i.webkitRelativePath && (n = "/" + i.webkitRelativePath.replace(/^\//, "")), i = new t(g.uid, i), i.relativePath = n, p.files.push(i), void

                                0)
                        }), "IE" !== a.browser && "IEMobile" !== a.browser) this.value = "";
                    else {
                        var n = this.cloneNode(!0);

                        this.parentNode.replaceChild(n, this), n.onchange = x
                    }
                    p.files.length && p.trigger("change")
                }, p.trigger({
                    type: "ready",
                    async: !0
                }), l = null
        },
        setOption: function(e, t) {
            var i = this.getRuntime(),
                r = n.get(i.uid);
            switch (e) {
                case "accept":
                    if (t) {
                        var

                            a = t.mimes || o.extList2mimes(t, i.can("filter_by_extension"));
                        r.setAttribute("accept", a.join(","))
                    } else

                        r.removeAttribute("accept");
                    break;
                case "directory":
                    t && i.can("select_folder") ? (r.setAttribute("directory", ""), r.setAttribute("webkitdirectory", "")) : (r.removeAttribute("directory"), r.removeAttribute("webkitdirectory"));
                    break;
                case "multiple":
                    t && i.can("select_multiple") ? r.setAttribute("multiple", "") : r.removeAttribute("multiple")
            }
        },
        disable: function(e) {
            var t, i = this.getRuntime();
            (t = n.get(i.uid)) && (t.disabled = !!e)
        },
        destroy: function() {
            var

                t = this.getRuntime(),
                i = t.getShim(),
                o = t.getShimContainer(),
                a = e && n.get(e.container),
                u = e && n.get(e.browse_button);
            a && r.removeAllEvents(a, this.uid), u &&

                (r.removeAllEvents(u, this.uid), u.style.zIndex = s), o &&

                (r.removeAllEvents(o, this.uid), o.innerHTML = ""), i.removeInstance(this.uid), e = o = a = u = i = null
        }
    })
}
return e.FileInput = s
}), n("moxie/runtime/html5/file/FileDrop",

        ["moxie/runtime/html5/Runtime", "moxie/file/File", "moxie/core/utils/Basic", "moxie/core/utils/Dom", "moxie/core/utils/Events", "moxie/core/utils/Mime"],
        function(e, t, i, n, r, o) {
            function a() {
                function e(e) {
                    if (!e.dataTransfer || !e.dataTransfer.types) return !1;
                    var

                        t = i.toArray(e.dataTransfer.types || []);
                    return -1 !== i.inArray("Files", t) || -1 !== i.inArray("public.file-url", t) || -1 !== i.inArray("application/x-moz-file", t)
                }

                function a(e, i) {
                    if (u(e)) {
                        var n = new

                        t(f, e);
                        n.relativePath = i || "", p.push(n)
                    }
                }

                function s(e) {
                    for (var t = [], n = 0; n < e.length; n++)[].push.apply(t, e[n].extensions.split(/\s*,\s*/));
                    return -1 === i.inArray("*", t) ? t : []
                }

                function u(e) {
                    if (!g.length) return !0;
                    var t = o.getFileExtension(e.name);
                    return !t || -1 !== i.inArray(t, g)
                }

                function c(e, t) {
                    var n = [];
                    i.each(e, function(e) {
                        var t = e.webkitGetAsEntry();

                        t && (t.isFile ? a(e.getAsFile(), t.fullPath) : n.push(t))
                    }), n.length ? l(n, t) : t()
                }

                function l(e, t) {
                    var n = [];
                    i.each(e, function(e) {
                        n.push(function(t) {
                            d(e, t)
                        })
                    }), i.inSeries(n, function() {
                        t()
                    })
                }

                function d(e, t)


                {
                    e.isFile ? e.file(function(i) {
                        a(i, e.fullPath), t()
                    }, function() {
                        t()
                    }) : e.isDirectory ? m(e, t) : t()
                }

                function m(e, t) {
                    function i(e) {
                        r.readEntries(function(t) {
                            t.length ? ([].push.apply(n, t), i(e)) : e()
                        }, e)
                    }
                    var n = [],
                        r = e.createReader();
                    i(function() {
                        l(n, t)
                    })
                }
                var h, f, p = [],
                    g = [];
                i.extend(this, {
                    init: function(t) {
                        var n, o = this;

                        h = t, f = o.ruid, g = s(h.accept), n = h.container, r.addEvent(n, "dragover", function(t) {
                            e(t) && (t.preventDefault(), t.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy")
                        }, o.uid), r.addEvent(n, "drop", function(t) {
                            e(t) && (t.preventDefault(), p = [], t.dataTransfer.items && t.dataTransfer.items[0].webkitGetAsEntry ? c(t.dataTransfer.items, function() {
                                o.files = p, o.trigger("drop")
                            }) : (i.each(t.dataTransfer.files, function(e) {
                                a(e)
                            }), o.files = p, o.trigger("drop")))
                        }, o.uid), r.addEvent(n, "dragenter", function() {
                            o.trigger("dragenter")
                        }, o.uid), r.addEvent(n, "dragleave", function() {
                            o.trigger("dragleave")
                        }, o.uid)
                    },
                    destroy: function() {
                        r.removeAllEvents(h && n.get(h.container), this.uid), f = p = g = h = null, this.getRuntime().getShim().removeInstance(this.uid)
                    }
                })
            }
            return e.FileDrop = a
        }), n("moxie/runtime/html5/file/FileReader", ["moxie/runtime/html5/Runtime", "moxie/core/utils/Encode", "moxie/core/utils/Basic"], function(e, t, i) {
            function n() {
                function e(e) {
                    return t.atob(e.substring(e.indexOf("base64,") + 7))
                }
                var n, r = !1;
                i.extend(this, {
                    read: function(t, o) {
                        var a = this;
                        a.result = "", n = new window.FileReader, n.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
                                a.trigger(e)
                            }), n.addEventListener("load", function(t) {
                                a.result = r ? e(n.result) : n.result, a.trigger(t)
                            }), n.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
                                a.trigger(e, n.error)
                            }), n.addEventListener("loadend", function(e) {
                                n = null, a.trigger(e)
                            }), "function" === i.typeOf(n[t]) ? (r = !1, n[t](o.getSource())) : "readAsBinaryString" === t &&

                            (r = !0, n.readAsDataURL(o.getSource()))
                    },
                    abort: function() {
                        n && n.abort()
                    },
                    destroy: function() {
                        n = null, this.getRuntime().getShim().removeInstance(this.uid)
                    }
                })
            }
            return
```

Comment: el tema es que ahí `file_upload` es un anchor que llama a un javascript, habría que ver que hace el javascript (si abre un modal u otra cosa) y así localizar el `input type="file"` que es el que recibiría el sendkeys (el nombre/ruta del archivo a subir)

Comment: Hola, gracias or contestar... acabo de buscar en el javaScript y es una locura... está codificado.. localicé el elemento pero el id es una varible... <input id="'+g.uid+'" type="file.... ¿Alguna ídea de que se puede hacer?

Comment: voy a intentar poner el fragmento de código de JavaScript ahí arriba

Comment: probaría también un wait luego del click en el A (para darle un tiempo al script) y de ahi intentar un `uid = driver.execute_script("return g.uid");` o tal vez buscarlo por selector `input[type="file"]`, tambien esperando unos milisegundos para que le de tiempo al render

Comment: Buena idea, gracias lo probaré a ver que tal

Comment: La segunda opción funcionó :-).... puse esto **img_upload = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']") ** y después esto **img_upload[0].send_keys(path_out)** ... Muchisimas Gracias @aloMalbarez, me acabas de salvar la vida... llevaba dos dias haciendo este código y tengo que subir al servidor casi 25000 imagenes...

Comment: buenísimo que te funcionó yo me colgué en poner la respuesta con las referencias =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mas referencia lo que hay ahí es un fileupload usando [moxie.js](https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie) un ejemplo de código no comprimido está en https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie/wiki/File-Picker

como te comentaba lo que generalmente funciona es enviarle el click al activador, esperar un poco y luego buscar el `INPUT type="file"` creado por la librería.

En caso de que sean varios creas una lista:

```
file_tag_list =driver.find_elements_by_xpath(//input[@type="file"])
```

y los accedes por índice

```
file_tag_list[0].send_keys(filepath)
file_tag_list[1].send_keys(filepath)
```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30397244/1423096